# Query where value in array field

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table called " User " in mysql database in Rails 5.

In that table, there is an array field called "professions" .

I want to find all Users that have a profession array that contains the value "writer" .

i have the following records:

```
=> #<User id: 39806, email: "user@gmail.com", professions: {"model"=>nil, "writer"=>nil, "graphic_producer"=>nil}>
```

I tried to do this but it didnt work

```
1)User.where("['writer'] = ANY (user.professions)")

2)User.where(:professions.in =>['writer'] )
```

Comment: How are you storing that array? Does MySQL support array columns? Are you using JSON? Maybe `serialize`?

Comment: @muistooshort the professions field is of type text. no Json

Comment: So you're using `serialize` in the model class to store YAML in the text column? Can you change the schema?

Comment: @muistooshort There is one serialize :professions in the user model. Change the schema? Do you mean change the type of field?

Comment: I am not using mysql, but if your column is text, would you try this `User.where("professions like ?", "%#{search_params}%")` search_params in your case could be `"writer'=>`, but you need check the professions column.

Comment: `serialize :professions` will leave a YAML version of your data in your text column, in your case it looks like you're getting a YAML-encoded hash rather than an array. Querying inside YAML is possible but ugly, error-prone, and generally unpleasant. If you change the column to JSON then you could use MySQL's JSON functions to query it; if you put them in a separate table (better IMO) then you could use simple SQL to query it. Either would require fixing all your existing data but you'll have to do that eventually, `serialize` is a trap that almost always bites you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize query to make it work